# Binary Arithmetic Operation

Tags: java, casting, compiler-errors, type-conversion

Why it is Compile time error respective of float and int both are of 4bytes?
I have searched on various sites but not getting the satisfactory answer

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a= 10.0F+10;
        System.out.println(a);

}
```

Please correct me if I am asking the question in the worng way, as I am new to stackOverflow

Comment: Just because two values are the same length in bits doesn't mean they are assignment-compatible. Mapping bits will give you nonsense answers.

Comment: @user3580294: Righto, otherwise you might also be able to cast `long` to `Object`; fun indeed.

Answer (score 3):

In converting types Java doesn't consider the size of memory used.  For example, you can implicitly convert from 64-bit `long` to 32-bit `float` as float has a wider range.

You cannot implicitly convert from `float` to `int` as this is considered narrowing and requires an explicit cast.

Note: the order you do conversions can matter

```
int a = (int) 10.0f + 123456787;
System.out.println("a = "+a);
int b = (int) (10.0f + 123456787);
System.out.println("b = "+b);
```

prints

```
a = 123456797 // expected
b = 123456792
```

You get a different result as 123456787 cannot be represented as a float without representation error.  However, 10.0F can be represented as an int accurately.

Similarly, casting in the order works best here.

```
int a = (int) 1.5f * 100;
System.out.println("a = "+a);
int b = (int) (1.5f * 100);
System.out.println("b = "+b);
```

prints

```
a = 100
b = 150 // expected
```

Answer (score 2):

the sum would result in `float` and you will have to cast it to `int` as it is not implicitly convertible

```
int a= (int) 10.0F + 10;
```

in your example you are adding `10.0` you don't need `float` here

Comment: Note: this might be different to `int a = (int) (10.0F + 10);` for different values of "10". ;)

Comment: See my answer for two examples, where one order or the other is better.